# Web API not working when doing POST passing a string to the method

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api

Why am I getting this error msg?
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://www.test.com:7043/API/RunningValue_Import'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'RunningValue_Import' that matches the request."}

Here is the code:

```
public class RunningValue_ImportController : ApiController
{
    string temp001 = ""; //breakpoint here but it wont enter into the function below

    // POST api/RunningValue_Import
    public object PostRunningValue_Import(string xml)
    {
        string temp = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            temp = xml;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            return new { isError = true, Msg = ee.ToString() };
        }
        return new { isError = false, Msg = "successful." };
    }
}
```

Fiddler:

```
POST http: //www.test.com:7043/API/RunningValue_Import HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.test.com:7043/Html/cURL.html
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0; ATT)
Host: www.test.com:7043
Content-Length: 12
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

xml=WhateverStringGoesHere
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action signature to `public object PostRunningValue_Import([FromBody]string xml)` as by default `string` type is expected to come from Uri.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default routing, then the request for URI = `http://www.test.com:7043/API/RunningValue_Import` will look for an `Index()` action method. Since your action method is named `PostRunningValue_Import`, it's not matching any route defined in the Routes `Dictionary`.

If you want, you can try giving it the `ActionName` as follows.

```
// POST api/RunningValue_Import    
[ActionName("Index")]
public object PostRunningValue_Import(string xml)
{
```

If you were curious, here's some interesting info on how a Method becomes an Action. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx/

Comment: I added the line of code you suggested but still no luck. The interesting thing is that I have other API Controllers that work just fine. And yes, I am using the default routing. Thanks